# Is there a way to capture a full resolution picture automatically and send it by email at certain hour each day?

Tags: photos, automation

If not a specific app, is there any way to achieve that by using existing applications (combination)?

Answer (score 3):

[Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en) or [Llama](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama&hl=en) should both be able to accomplish this, from what I understand, though I have never tested them with taking pictures.